# When reading a file how can you set the input as a string and not as a filePath using apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I tried defining a String called source that holds the path to where I want the files to be transfered from.
Here is an example of my code:

```
String currentDate = sdf.format(date);
String source = "C:\\files\\" + currentDate;
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("file:source?noop=true")
```

So, what I basically want to do is: Everyday a new folder is created into a specific location named after the current date (for example: 20191001,20190930) and that is what currentDate string is for.
The code works when instead of source I put the specific file path (from("file:C:\everything for java\moveInValidFiles\files\20191001?noop=true") ) but for this I would like to use a string that holds the path since everyday I get new folders. Is there anyway I could to this?

Answer (score 0):

> How can you set the input as a string and not as (part of) a filePath

Think in java way. Treat it as a java variable instead of a pure String.

```
String currentDate = sdf.format(date);
String source = "C:\\files\\" + currentDate;
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:" + source + "?noop=true")
```

> How to collect files from directory created daily with specific naming pattern

The file consumer (the from part) is set once when the route is created and used forever until the route is being destroyed. So, you could have following ways

1. Have your own mechanism to recreate the route (with different directory path) everyday
2. Use [Camel File Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) query parameter `filterDirectory`
   (e.g. `"file:C:\\files?noop=true&filterDirectory=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}"`)